# jQuery counts background-image aspect ratio and changes padding value of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I hope that someone can help me or give me some instructions how to achieve this.
I have fluid div, without height and with width:100%. I want to display background-image which will fit to the screen size and this div element. But sadly I can't use background cover or any other solutions that can normally work in modern browsers. I also can't setup fixed height (it has to be responsive)
I've found a solution by using aspect ratio of an image - it's using padding-bottom percentage value but this solution works only with fixed aspect ratio for example for a 16:9 or 4:3. And I need something that will be realy fluid.
So I figured it out, that I need some script which will be automatically checking background image aspect ratio and will be changing padding-bottom value according to images aspect ratio. But I'm not sure how to this. I know only the basics of the jQuery.

So I’m searching for a script (jQuery) which will be checking the background-image aspect ratio and according to this will change padding-bottom of an element (div).

Let’s say that I’ve got:

HTML:

```
<div class=“container”>
    <div style=“background-image: url(‘image.png’)”></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

So it will check the aspect ratio of an image (image.png) and will change padding-bottom percentage value (in .container class), example:

**image aspect ratio: 16:9**

**Height / Width x 100% ** in this case: **9/16 x 100% = 56.25%**

**padding-bottom: 56.25%;**

Is it possible ?

If it is not possible to make this change in css file it can be also applied inside the inline css, like here:

```
<div class=“container” style=“padding-bottom:56.25%”>
    <div style=“background-image: url(‘image.png’)”></div>
</div>
```

Any solutions using background-image:cover / contain or any other won't be a solutions that will fit my needs. Sadly I need to do this by using jquery which will be checking the aspect ratio.

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: Construct a new `Image` object in JS, assign the background image URL to its `src` attribute (pay attention to using the correct path if you want to read that value from the styles dynamically), and then in the load handler for that image read its dimensions …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var image_url = "image.png";

// preload image
var img = new Image();


img.onload = function() {
    var ratio = img.height / img.width x 100;

     $(".container").css("padding-bottom", ratio + "%");
}

img.src = image_url;
```

Comment: Will work in that way only if the image is already loaded, so that width and height can be read “immediately”. Better to use a load handler, and read the values from within that.

Comment: Good, but you should reverse the order of assigning the load handler and the image source – otherwise, for an already loaded image it might(!) happen that the load event gets fired already before the handler is set, and then nothing will happen.

Comment: actually, if you put your answer, I will upvote for you because I didn't even know that. I will delete mine.

Comment: Nah, just keep it – and see it as “working together” on the solution ;-)

Comment: That's great guys, Thanks a lot :)I'm thinking, is there any possibility to make this script to get background-image url from the div automaticaly ? Like: `var imgage_url = $('#div_with_bg').css('background-image').replace(/^url|[()]/g, '');"`

Comment: I need to answer myself question :) I think I solved it. `function extractUrl(input)
  {  
    
    return input.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
   }
   
   var image_url = extractUrl($("#advert").css("background-image"));
   // preload image
   var img = new Image();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the calculated value for the padding-bottom attribute in a variable named varPercentage:

Give an id to the container div.

```
<div class=“container” id="containerDiv">
  <div style=“background-image: url(‘image.png’)”></div>
</div>
```

Use jQuery css function to set/modify the padding-bottom attribute:

```
$('#containerDiv').css("padding-bottom", varPercentage);
```

Comment: That’s not what the question is about – it is about _getting_ the aspect ratio for a given image.

Comment: My bad. I saw the algorythm and assumed it was implemented.